# Determine if an array of arrays of characters can be concatenated in order, into a substring of haystack

Tags: python, algorithm, python-3.x, strings

> Algorithm: Determine if an array of arrays of characters can be
>   concatenated in order, into a substring of haystack.
>
> Example:
>
> ```
> [['a','A','@'], ['b','B','8'], ['c','(','[']]
> ```
>
> This list can be combined by selecting from each of the subarrays in
>   order, such as:
>
> `abc, ab(, ab[, Abc, Ab(` etc.
>
> Are any of these combinations substrings of the search string?
>
> ```
> "123 easy as Ab(" # True
> "123 easy as Abb" # False
> "123 easy as @b(" # True
> "123 easy as Abc" # False
> ```

Python 3

```
combos = [['a','A','@'], ['b','B','8'], ['c','(','[']]
search = "123 easy as Ab(" # True

def find_mutated_string(offset, combos, search):
    for i, char in enumerate(search):
        for mutant in combos[offset]:
            if mutant == char:
                if len(combos) == (offset+1):
                    # Last letter combo found
                    return True
                else:
                    return find_mutated_string(offset+1, combos, search[i+1:])
    # Didn't find mutant char in search string
    return False

print(find_mutated_string(0, combos, search))
```

Answer (score 3):

## bug

You don't reset the `offset` when there is a mismatch, so `"123 easy as b("` also returns `True`. Just add:

```
    else:
        offset = 0
```

## optional parameter `offset`

The caller of the function should not care about the offset if he wants to check whether a combination is part of the string. I would change the method signature to `def find_mutated_string2(combos, search, offset=0)`. Then your user doesn't need to worry about this

## in

Python has the `in` statement.

Your code says

```
    for mutant in combos[offset]:
        if mutant == char:
```

but actually mean: `if char in combos[offset]`

Since `in` in a `list` traverses the list to look for a match, while set uses a lookup, defining the combos as `set`s helps here

```
combos = [{"@", "A", "a"}, {"8", "B", "b"}, {"(", "[", "c"}]


def find_mutated_string2(combos, search, offset=0):
    for i, char in enumerate(search):
        if char in combos[offset]:
            if len(combos) == (offset + 1):
                return True
            else:
                return find_mutated_string2(combos, search[i+1:], offset+1)
        else:
            offset = 0
    return False
```

## match substring

You could write a helper function that takes a substring and checks whether this matches the combo's

```
def matches_combos(substring, combos):
    return len(substring) == len(combos) and all(
        char in combo for char, combo in zip(substring, combos)
    )
```

This can be easily tested:

```
test_cases = {
    "abc": True,
    "Ab[": True,
    "abd": False,
    "ab": False,
    "abcd": False,
}
for substring, answer in test_cases.items():
    result = matches_combos(substring, combos)
    assert result == answer
```

## recursion

If your string is long, you will run into the [recursion limit](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3323001/1562285).

```
for i in range(10000):
    try:
        _ = find_mutated_string2(combos, "a"*i)
    except RecursionError:
        print(f"fails for string length: {i}")
        break
```

> ```
> fails for string length: 5921
> ```

for a recursionlimit of 3000

You can easily rewrite this proble iteratively

```
def find_mutated_string3(combos, search):
    if len(search) < len(combos):
        return False
    for i in range(len(search) - 2):
        substring = search[i : i + len(combos)]
        if matches_combos(substring, combos):
            return True
```

or using `any`

```
def find_mutated_string4(combos, search):
    if len(search) < len(combos):
        return False
    return any(
        matches_combos(search[i : i + len(combos)], combos)
        for i in range(len(search) - 2)
    )
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch! How likely am I to hit the recursion limit? I guess the search string must be at least 998 characters or so for this to happen?